# Should i use Django to convert my Command line application?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have this "tiny" application who grew faster than i expected and actually is the core tool for deployments,  but actually the only thing that limits this tool is being on a command line. I was thinking about migrate it to a web application because it would be more friendly for some users, and the most important i could manage the multi-processes launched. To have a picture  of what i want to achieve is almost a datagrid  with two rows only ( for example ):

- Type row ( http or ftp process )
- Status row (started/ running / completed / error )

In short this tool uses the following , and i the only thing i need to know is if i can achieve the same using django:

- DB Query ( Using sqlalchemy )
- Xml/Html Parsing
- Multithreading
- Ftp usage ( upload/download/listing )
- Http requests ( actually i'm using requests )

So, Django  could help me to remove the limitation of the command line ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [help/dont-ask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! But where i could ask this? superuser?

Comment: Generally, nowhere on the Stack Exchange network. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/ as well.

Comment: Well, i'm going to remove Flask then, and edit the question to  be more specific.. since i really need an answer for this =(

Comment: Your question is still too broad as well; many a command line applications can be converted to a web application, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea or that command line applications are more limited than a web application.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Well, for some experts it could be too broad or converting a command line tool to a web aplication would not be a good  idea.. But the main thing is... this site is only for experts? I mean, i consider myself a casual developer and sometimes i use this site to help me on some ideas. Again.. this question can be very broad for who have more experience, but for me, fits perfectly for what i need. :)

Comment: You should probably say what your application does, and where you see the limits of the command line tool. What specifically would be improved with a web app.

Comment: @Thales: yes, this is a site for experts, and one reason the experts keep coming back is because the quality standards for questions are so strict. We ask you to keep questions focused on specific topics; this question could require pages of caveats and explanations to answer instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the Patience and for clarifying that. i think then this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oviously noone can make the decision for you, but maybe I compare Django & Flask a little:

Flask is supposed to be a **micro**-framework like bottle, cherrypy etc. Meaning it has *no* build in database, you can and have to choose one on your own.

Django is a full-featured complex webframework, it brings it's own ORM & databases, although it's possible to change them.

For a tiny application a microframework might already suit your needs.

Comment: a broad answer for a broad question =)

But answered for what i need to know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would look into Flask + the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension.